# CUDA function to increase an array values

Tags: cuda

when I use this code in cuda it only increase a[0],a[1],a[2] other was 0 (didn't increased)

```
   __global__ void inc2(int * a){
        int i= threadIdx.x;
        i%=10;
        atomicAdd(&(a[i]),1);
    }
```

when I write

```
__global__ void inc2(int * a){
    int i= threadIdx.x;
    i%=10;
    atomicAdd(&(a[6]),1);
}
```

it didn't increase a[6]

what's wrong? sorry

all of the code is this

```
__global__ void inc2(int * a){
    int i= threadIdx.x;
    i%=10;
    atomicAdd(&(a[6]),1);
}
int main()
{

    //=============================================
    int aaa[10]={0};
    int *q;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&q,100);
    cudaMemcpy(q,aaa,10,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    inc2<<<100,100>>>(q);
    cudaMemcpy(aaa,q,10,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("%d\t",aaa[i]);
    }
    cudaFree(q);
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code.

You may be confused about the size parameters associated with functions like `cudaMalloc` or `cudaMemcpy`.  [They represent a size](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g48efa06b81cc031b2aa6fdc2e9930741) in *bytes*.  So this:

```
cudaMemcpy(aaa,q,10,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

only transfers 10 bytes, which is 2.5 `int` quantities.  If you want to see the modified value of `a[6]`, you're going to have to transfer more than the first 2 `int` quantities in `a`.

If you modify these lines:

```
cudaMemcpy(q,aaa,40,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
                 ^^
```

and:

```
cudaMemcpy(aaa,q,40,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
                 ^^
```

I think you'll have better results.

Comment: `sizeof(int)*10` instead of `40` is generally cleaner: i.e. it is clearer what you have in mind and where the numbers come from.